# Is fake performance of salah during monthly cycle okay?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, menses

In our family, when we have our monthly cycle, we actually feel very embarrassed and so we hide it. During prayer time we actually fake our prayers and just act of doing salah while we actually don't pray, we just fake our whole salah with ruku and shujud and everything else.

Is it a sin? Allah knows why we do that and so I'm actually confused if it's ok. From my childhood I have seen my mom and sisters never ever took any breaks from salah and so after I had my period started I felt ashamed of expressing that im having period and so I also started faking my salah during my period. We never talk about these at home even among our sisters and mom as if period is something really embarrassing thing to talk about!

Can you please give me some suggestion what to do? I feel like I should fake my salah just to hide my monthly cycle, but yet I cant make myself to break out of these embarrassing feelings!

Comment: There is nothing to be ashamed of, it is only natural and you have no control over it. Even if you don't hide it you don't really have to declare it to anyone. Your just being silly and placing unnecessary burdon on yourself, and what if they did find out, are they gonna    cut all ties with you? NO, because it is stupid

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any reports that women in the time of the Prophet used to 'fake' prayers. If they didn't do this then one should ask themselves whether they consider themselves to have more *haya* than the Mothers of the Believers and the Sahabiyas?

Secondly some schools derive that physical actions such as *sajdah* are part of prayer and shouldn't be done in a state of ritual impurity. For reference [Muwatta Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/404852).

Comment: What about a menstruating woman who for instance eat during Ramadan outside while everyone else fast? Maybe another issue, but in this case too people would guess that the woman in menstruating